# Vue Router Invalid route component

Tags: vue.js, router

I am new into Vue and web developement and without a error message i am not able to solve the problem. I can start the developement server and the Navbar loads but the navigation doesnt work.

Any ideas?
I guess there could be a problem with the  inside the main tag. But i cant place it outside

App.vue

```
<template>
  <main id="sidenav">
    <img src="./img/logo.png" width="240" height="80" style="align=left">
    <hr>
    <div id="navbox">
      <img src="./img/icons8-dashboard-layout-24.png" width="40" height="40">
      <router-link to="/" id="link">Dashboard</router-link>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="navbox">
     <img src="./img/icons8-transformationsfertigkeit-50.png" width="40" height="40">
      <router-link to="/prozesse" id="link">Prozesse</router-link>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="navbox">
     <img src="./img/icons8-gute-verbindung-50.png" width="40" height="40">
      <router-link to="/verbindungsdaten" id="link">Verbindungsdaten</router-link>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <router-view/>
  </main>
</template>
```

Verbindungsdaten.vue

```
<template>
    <body>
      <div class="Verbindungsdaten">
        <h1> Verbindungsdaten </h1>
      </div>
    </body>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src

export default {
  name: 'Verbindungsdaten'
}
</script>
```

index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Dashboard from '../views/Dashboard.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: Dashboard
  },
  {
    path: '/prozesse',
    name: 'prozesse'
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    //    component: () =>
    //      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/prozesse.vue")
  },
  {
    path: '/verbindungsdaten',
    name: 'verbindungsdaten'
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    // component: () =>
    //  import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/verbindungsdaten.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: '/version',
    name: 'version'
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    // component: () =>
    //  import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/version.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: '/prüfung',
    name: 'prüfung'
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    // component: () =>
    //  import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/prüfung.vue"),
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: Your routes do not have a `component` key set (because they're commented out)…

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem...